# OData: how to implement @odata.bind to insert foreign key value to a table from .NET 6 using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

In Postman I can POST request successfully with this raw data:

```
{
       "relatedContact@odata.bind": "Contacts(3b36c706-6a6c-414f-8f5f-ed24fc9a5aa2)",
       "stringName": "Shrek Rattle"
}
```

This will insert `3b36c706-6a6c-414f-8f5f-ed24fc9a5aa2` into the `relatedContact` column and 'Shrek Rattle' in stringName column of the `PreferenceManagement` table. `Contact` and `PreferenceManagement` tables have a one-to-many relationship via `ContactId` from `Contact` table and `relatedContact` in the `PreferenceManagement` table.

This is working fine when trying in Postman, and I'm able to see the posted records in `PreferenceManagement` table in the database.

My problem is, HOW can I apply this same functionality in .NET 6 using C#?

From Swagger/UI, I tried sending that same post request but I always get a '400 Bad Request' result!

Note: when calling PostAsync for table that doesn't have foreign key values to be inserted, it's also working just fine. For example, if I just enter `{ "stringName": "Shrek Rattle" }` in Swagger/UI and click the `Post` button, I'm not getting any issue in my code and the data is posted into the `PreferenceManagement` table, but with a null `relatedContact` value. But I need that `relatedContact` value as it will relates the `Contact` records to the `Preference` records.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance for any help, suggestions, and recommendations!

- I created the code in ASP.NET Core 6 using C#.
- We have Contact, and `PreferenceManagement` tables in Dynamics CRM.
- In PreferenceManagementtable has the `stringName` and `relatedContact` columns that needs to be populated when making a `POST` request
- I created a `PreferenceManagement` class with just two string properties (`stringName, relatedContact`).

Supplied values in Swagger/UI:

```
{
   "relatedContact": "3b36c706-6a6c-414f-8f5f-ed24fc9a5aa2",
   "stringName": "Shrek Rattle"
}
```

I'm expecting that the values will be inserted in the respective columns of the `PreferenceManagement` table. But I'm always getting 400 Bad Request exception.